# Authorize with Tumblr API 2.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, tumblr

I am trying to post something, using the Tumblr API — but I cannot even connect to the API!

I have the following AJAX call (all keys have been removed for this example):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/tomjhume.tumblr.com/post",
    dataType:'jsonp',
    data: {
        api_key : "XXXXXX"
    },
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response, arguments);
    }
 });
```

However, it returns `"Not Authorized"` with a `401`. I have since authorized with Tumblr, and they have given me this code:

```
// Authenticate via OAuth
var tumblr = require('tumblr.js');
var client = tumblr.createClient({
  consumer_key: 'XXXXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXXXX',
  token: 'XXXXX',
  token_secret: 'XXXXX'
});

// Make the request
client.userInfo(function (err, data) {
    // ...
});
```

However, I am unsure how to implement it, and can't find a tutorial. How do I combine the `$.ajax`function with what Tumblr has given me?

Comment: The code they've given you is for Node.js, a server-side implementation of javascript. It cannot run in a browser. You don't want to be using the API client-sided as your API key will be available to the public.

Comment: For reference, here is the repo for Tumblr.js: https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.js/

Answer (score 0):

From [Tumblr's API page](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2):

> The API uses three different levels of authentication, depending on
>   the method.
>
> - None: No authentication. Anybody can query the method.
> - API key: Requires an API key. Use your OAuth Consumer Key as your api_key.
> - OAuth: Requires a signed request that meetsthe OAuth 1.0a Protocol.

You can only make calls that don't need OAuth straight from the browser, using the ajax code you posted.

If your call requires OAuth, you need to route your calls through your own server. For example

1. make an ajax call to your server
2. on your server will pull the data from Tumblr using [tumblr.php](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php)
3. send the data back to the browser by responding to the ajax call